# javascript Getting distance of child element from top-left corner of Parent element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Is there a way to get the offset of a ChildElement from a given parent element?

for example if a DIV in contained within a parent DIV with id "xyz"

is there a way to say

```
parent = $("xyz");
child = $("abc");

child.offset(parent);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A convenient method is [`Element.getPositionedOffset()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/positionedOffset/), but only when the parent element has a `position` style property.

```
var offset = $('abc').positionedOffset();
offset.left;
offset.top;
```

Otherwise it takes a little more work:

```
var parent = $('xyz',
    child = $('abc'),
    offset = child.viewportOffset().relativeTo(parent.viewportOffset());
```

The advantage here is the two elements need not be directly related, any pair of elements on the page can do.